# ¿Qué pasa si el heap y el stack se encuentran?

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria, proceso, stack, heap

¿Qué pasa si el heap y el stack se encuentran? ¿El comportamiento es igual si el heap se encuentra con el stack que si el stack se encuentra con el heap?

Intento encontrar un programa en C que aclare este comportamiento pero está siendo imposible.

Comment: Hola Anita, te damos la bienvenida a la comunidad. Esta pregunta es muy interesante. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Traducción de la [respuesta de Norman Ramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335389/3695983) para una pregunta similar en Stack Overflow.

En los lenguajes de programación modernos en un sistema operativo moderno, o bien recibirás un desbordamiento de pila (*stack overflow*), o bien `malloc()`, `sbrk()` o `mmap()` fallarán cuando intentes incrementar el heap. Pero no todo el software es moderno, así que vamos a ver los modos de fallo:

- Si el stack crece y se encuentra con el heap, el típico compilador de C empezará a sobreescribir de manera silenciosa las estructuras de datos del heap. En los sistemas operativos modernos habrá una o más páginas de salvaguarda de memoria virtual que prevendrán que el stack crezca indefinidamente. Mientras la cantidad de memoria de las páginas de guardia sea al menos tan grande como el tamaño del registro de activación del procedimiento que crece, el SO te garantizará un fallo de segmentación (*segfault* o *segmentation fault*). Si estás corriendo tu programa en DOS o una máquina sin MMU... entonces tienes problemas graves.
- Si el heap crece y se encuentra con el stack, el sistema operativo deberá estar al tanto de la situación y algún tipo de llamada al sistema fallará. La implementación de `malloc()` definitivamente detectará el fallo y devolverá `NULL`. Lo que ocurra después depende de ti.

Siempre me sorprende la voluntad de los desarrolladores de compiladores para esperar que el sistema operativo tenga sistemas de salvaguarda para prevenir desbordamiento de pila. Por supuesto, ese truco funciona bien hasta que empiezas a tener miles de hilos, cada uno con su propio stack...